# Setting up a simple email alias to forward to 15 people

Tags: email, mailgun

### Short question:

Is there a way to reliably deliver emails using mailgun routes without getting this error message:

Failed: redacted@yahoo.com → redacted@gmail.com 'Re: Sample Subject Line' Server response: 550 550 5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's 5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact administrator of yahoo.com domain if 5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about DMARC 5.7.1 initiative. pw18si13572314vdb.85 - gsmtp

I like using mailgun routes because it meets my needs perfectly... but it seems that I can't reliably deliver mail to multiple recipients this way.

---

### Long Story

I'm trying to find a service that will allow me to

1. create an email alias, mylist@mydomain.com
2. Send emails to mylist@mydomain.com and have that single email delivered to 10-20 people with me as the sender and mylist@mydomain.com in the to field (so "reply" goes to the sender and "reply-all" goes to everyone)

Mailgun routes fit this perfectly

I read their API docs and implemented a solution to read from our group database and make web calls to update my routes.  Everything is great.

Everything worked great until I started getting the DMARC messages.  Is there a way to avoid this?  We're a small group (but dynamic) group and we'd like to make sending emails easy.

Thanks~!

Comment: Hi, did you set up successfully SPF and DKIM on your domain?

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how you configured Mailgun to display the sender's email address in the reply-to field. I also want exactly the same functionality but it seems that the reply-to field has the name of alias instead of the actual sender by default.

Comment: Try to put the email between angular brackets and the name to be displayed plain text ex: 'Alex Cat <alex.cat@gmail.com>'

Comment: @AlexSpurling - I ended up using Mail ROUTES instead of the mailing list.  The mailing list feature always replaced the reply-to with the mailing list email address.  By setting up a mail route, I had more control over this sort of thing.

Comment: @API_sheriff_orlie - I'm pretty sure I set up DKIM and SPF on my domain... in the end I ended up dropping this whole project because I'd get 100% delivery rate to people with gmail addresses, 50% delivery with yahoo, and nearly 0% with AOL and MSN.

Comment: @ColoradoTechie What is/are Mail ROUTES?

Comment: @AlexSpurling - log in to mailgun and go to https://mailgun.com/cp/routes . They let you "route" messages to other email boxes. I had mailing_list@mydomain.com setup as a route that would "forward" to private_email@gmail.com, private_email2@gmail.com, someoneelse@gmail.com, etc.  When you use mailroutes the original to: field is kept intact and the reply field shows the original sender.  This would work AWESOME, except many other email providers started blocking my mail. I ended up dropping the idea (even though I wasn't spamming, these were team emails that yahoo, msn, and aol were blocking)

Answer (score 1):

Mailgun is now providing mailing list support, so you only need to create a new mailing list `mylist@mydomain.com`, add members to it, and then each members can discuss by sending an email to `mylist@mydomain.com`.

See https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#mailing-lists

Comment: Why -1 ? Would be great to add a comment when doing a downvote.